# error: anachronistic old-style base class initializer while using cmake

Tags: c++

I am trying to run the code in repository [Link](https://github.com/harishd10/TopoMap).
Here, is the Google Colab link which installs all the libraries as required to run the repository. - [Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18D0L4eSb7ZGp8m6ti2b6umeEC7gfjxG_?usp=sharing)
In the link, there are two ways I have built the project. One is using qmake and the other is using cmake. Both of them give me the same errors.

I searched for the error in question but gave me some answers that were 7 years old. Considering the code in the repository is built in 2020, I doubt there is a problem in the code.
I think the problem may be with the version of gcc/g++.

Version:
GCC/G++ : 7.5.
The code that throws the error:

```
#define len(p) (std::sqrt(p.x * p.x + p.y * p.y))
```

The above code is present in src/geomutils.h line 31.

Does this code follow some specific C++ version like C++-11, C++-14, etc.?

Comment: Most likely the problem is related to how the `len(p)` macro is being called.  If you can include that line in your question, you'll be more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained and not require visiting external links to answer. Please form a [mre] for the issue and post that instead and also include the full error message (with all the informational messages accompanying it). The shown line of code will not by itself or if used properly generate the error and there doesn't really seem to be anything wrong with it (except that it should be a function, not a macro, and that it should be named different because of the risk for a naming conflict).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a proprocessor macro named `len()`.  We can tell from the GCC error message that the file `/usr/include/mlpack/core/data/serialization_shim.hpp` contains the code `len(len)` inside it, which is presumably intended to initialize the `len` member of a class.  But the preprocessor is inserting your code there and causing syntax errors.

Rename `len` to something less likely to be used in other code, or make sure you only define it *after* including all third-party header files.

Comment: Or make `len` a function instead of a macro. There is no benefit to having it be a macro at all.

Comment: @user17732522: What, you don't consider "inlined even with optimizations disabled" an absolutely critical feature that is worth the terribleness that all these poorly defined macros lead to? Clearly no one knows how to enable optimization, and the only solution is MOAR MACROS! /s :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @user17732522. But I am not the author of the code I am just using the code. Making the change the worked!.